# AngularJs promise in forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have method for getting data from server.
And I use it in foreach, and after it need bind him to $scope variable.
Like this:

```
var qualityMix = [];
var engagementMix = [];
angular.forEach(versions, function (versions) {
    qualityMix.push(qualityScoreByTimeWithAppVerPromise(versions.version));
    engagementMix.push(engagementByTimeWithAppVerPromise(versions.version));
});

$scope.qualityScoreByTimeMix = function () {
    return $timeout(function () {
        return $q.all(qualityMix).then(function (data) {
            return {series: data};
        });
    });
};

$scope.engagementTimeMix = function () {
    return $q.all(engagementMix).then(function (data) {
        return {series: data};
    });
};
```

**qualityScoreByTimeWithAppVerPromise** and **engagementByTimeWithAppVerPromise** it is functions for getting data from server. Then **$scope.engagementTimeMix** and **$scope.qualityScoreByTimeMix** need return functions with promise (is okay).

This code working but not always, some times I catch exceptions **$scope.xxx is not a function**.

I don't know how to fix it. Help me please. Thanks a lot!

**UPD**
It is code for build charts.

```
<div class="section">
    <highchart id="mix_quality_score_by_time" type="area" data="qualityScoreByTimeMix"
               chart-style="qualityScoreMixChartStyle"></highchart>
</div>
```

And my directive I invoke in other page, like this:

```
<compare-versions id="compare_versions_panel" start-day="timeFilter.startDay()"></compare-versions>
```

$scope.xxx is not a function
I mean what I catch message in chrome console what
    $scope.engagementTimeMix and $scope.qualityScoreByTimeMix it not a function

Comment: Could we see your controller and where you are actually calling these methods?

Comment: Exactly what is $scope.xxx? I don't see anything being called here just setting up for things being called. I don't see where you call $scope.qualtyScoreByTimeMix  (no need for $timeout there) or $scope.engagementTimeMix

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if and draw graph when you already have value
example:

```
<div class="section" ng-if="qualityScoreByTimeMix">
    <highchart id="mix_quality_score_by_time" type="area" data="qualityScoreByTimeMix" chart-style="qualityScoreMixChartStyle"></highchart>
</div>
```