# AngularJS promise after foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a problem with my promise after a foreach,

I would like to remove the object which has no parent from my database.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35201724/5453732) and I tried many things, for example this:

**controller**

```
project.getAll().then(function(results) {
            return $scope.array_projects = results;
        }).then(function(array_projects) {
            $scope.results = [];
            console.log(array_projects);

            angular.forEach(array_projects, function(result) {
                console.log(result);

                var project = new Project(result);

                var promise = project.getOne(result.ParentId);
                $scope.result.push(promise);
                promise.then(function(results) {
                    return results.length ? project:null;
                });
                
                // if(result.ParentId !== null) {
                //     console.log('ParentId');
                //     var promise = project.getOne(result.ParentId).then(function(results) {
                //         //console.log(results);
                //
                //         if (results.length === 0){
                //             console.log('remove children');
                //         } else {
                //             $scope.results.push(project);
                //             console.log('parent exist, children added!');
                //
                //         }
                //
                //     });
                //
                // }

            });

            // after forEach
            $q.all($scope.results).then(function(results){
                console.log($scope.results);
                // result is an array of mixed Project object or null value, just remove the null value and you're fine :)
                var trueResults = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                    if(results[i]){
                        trueResults.push(results[i]);
                    }
                }
                // now use trueResults
                console.log(trueResults);
            })

        });
```

**model**

```
var Project = function (properties) {
        // Model
        this.description = null;
        this.file        = null;
        this.name        = null;
        this.ParentId    = null;
        this.path        = null;

        angular.extend(this, properties);
    };

// With service
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Project.prototype.getAll = function () {
    return ProjectService.getAll();
};

Project.prototype.getOne = function (id) {
    return ProjectService.getOne(id);
};
```

**project.service.js**

```
this.getAll = function (params) {
    var projects = [];
    return db.selectAll('projects').then(function(results) {
        for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            projects.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        return projects;
    });
};

this.getOne = function (id) {
    var project = [];
    console.log(id);
    return db.select('projects', {
        "id": id
    }).then(function(results) {
        for(i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            project.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        return project;
    })
};
```

But my console.log($scope.results); show '[]'

In my BDD I have :

```
id/id/ParentId/name/file/date

5   5       test    crm-site.net    /release.txt    2016-04-26 08:43:17

6   6   5   test2   crm-site.net    /release.txt    2016-04-26 08:43:19

7   7       test3   crm-site.net    /release.txt    2016-04-26 08:43:20

8   8   7   test4   crm-site.net    /release.txt    2016-04-26 08:43:21
```

Comment: What did this `console.log(results)` display instead of `console.log($scope.results);`?

Answer (score 0):

You wasn't so far of what you were trying just update your code with :

```
// in the foreach
if(result.ParentId){
    var promise = project.getOne(result.ParentId);
    $scope.result.push(promise);
    promise.then(function(results) { 
        return results.length ? project:null;
    }
}
// after forEach
$q.all($scope.results).then(function(results){
    // result is an array of mixed Project object or null value, just remove the null value and you're fine :) 
   var trueResults = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
      if(results[i]){
          trueResults.push(results[i]);
      }
   } 
   // now use trueResults
})
```

The explanation is that $q.all take an array of promise not objects, he can't wait that you fill an array, because he can't know what criteria makes you're array "ready" unlike a promise where the resolve will be called.

Comment: Thx ! I updated my code with you code, but it doesn't work.. I have an error angular.min.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at Object.whereClause (angular-websql.js:7)
    at Object.select (angular-websql.js:7)
    at getOne (project.service.js:18)

Comment: my bad it's promise.then of course not project.getOne().then when it's already done 2 lines before. Bad copy / paste :x. I edited my own post

Comment: as i said in the coments in my code you have to remove null values from the array.  I added the relevant code for this. The resulting array will be stored in `trueResults`

Comment: Thx ! I try to find where is the mistake.. but I have always the same error

Comment: hum strange, i think this is because my .then is executed before the one in your service. What does match to the line 18 if `project.service.js` ?

Comment: return db.select('projects', {

Comment: can you log the id value and the results value in that function please ? Maybe result.ParentId is null ?

Comment: Sure ! Just before line 18, I write a console.log(id) and, it's "null"

Comment: then it comes from your code : i edited my own code, wrapping the code inside the forEach with a `if(result.ParentId)`

Comment: @Walfrat: you want to push the promise returned by the `.then`, not the promise returned by the `getOne`: `var promise =project.getOne(result.ParentId).then(function(results) { 
    return results.length ? project:null;
}` otherwise the `$q.all()` gets the raw results rather than the projects.

Comment: uh ? it's supposed to be the same object, if not, yes do so.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are misunderstanding how to use $q.all.
Each time you call a `project.getOne`, you don't know when the result will come as it is asynchonious. 
If you want to use the $q.all, you should push all the `project.getOne` in an array and `$q.all(myArray)`. It is normal that your code only show [] because the .then aren't called yet and the push method haven't been called yet when you go through the console.